# TypeScript does not infer about delete operator and spread operator?

Tags: typescript

```
interface Test {
    a: string;
    b: number;
    c: number;
}

const test = {
    a: 'a',
    b: 1,
    d: []
};

delete test.d;

const test2:Test = { ...test, c:1 };
=> Type '{ a: string; b: number; c: number; d: never[]; }' is not assignable to type 'Test'.
=> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'd' does not exist in type 'Test'.
```

I deleted **d** property by **delete** operator, but I got a error like that.

Is there a way for the situation?

Comment: I think it is case, when type casting with `const test2:Test = { ...test, c:1 } as Test;` is acceptably.

Comment: @Pavel Thanks for your idea!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type of the variable is infered on assignment, and I don't think Typescript does any flow control magic with the delete operator.  You could the spread operator to get rid of `d`:

```
interface Test {
    a: string;
    b: number;
    c: number;
}

const test = {
    a: 'a',
    b: 1,
    d: []
};

let { d, ...test3} = test

const test2:Test = { ...test3, c:1 };
```

Comment: It's a good idea, except that additional variable are used. Thank you! :)

Comment: @leftclick not ideal i know, there may be other solutions ... i can think of one with an extra function, or one that usses a type guard .. but none are perfect

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a tsconfig.json file, consider adding:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
     "strictNullChecks": false, 
    }
    ...
}
```