# how to delete a property from an object in Typescript without the operand of a 'delete' operator must be optional error?

Tags: typescript

I have tried to read how to delete a property from an object in here: [How do I remove a property from a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

it should use `delete`, I try it like this

```
const eventData = {...myEvent}; // myEvent is an instance of my `Event` class
delete eventData.coordinate; // I have error in here
```

but I have error like this

[image]

> The operand of a 'delete' operator must be optional.ts(2790)

and then I read this : [Typescript does not infer about delete operator and spread operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49590146/typescript-does-not-infer-about-delete-operator-and-spread-operator)

it seems to remove that error is by changing my tsconfig.json file using

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
     "strictNullChecks": false, 
    }
    ...
}
```

but if I implement this, I will no longer have null checking

so how to delete a property from an object in Typescript without the operand of a 'delete' operator must be optional error?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Typescript warns you about breaking the contract (the object won't have the required property anymore). One of the possible ways would be omitting the property when you cloning the object:

```
const myEvent = {
    coordinate: 1,
    foo: 'foo',
    bar: true
};

const { coordinate, ...eventData } = myEvent;
// eventData is of type { foo: string; bar: boolean; }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwKIDcCmZYF4YG8BQMRMoIATgCYCWYAhlGgFwwCMANIcQGYgjMDkPEPw7EYAI1plmUMgFc0%20AL4BufOtCRYuEr0o16aNjAB0ZtOkwARerRhKYORKgxQ1AencwLrm1DtUEDAgXDBQCAAOaHgwQszQZDQA5ioSUszivAA2aLRgqUpAA)

---

> Operands for `delete` must be optional.
> When using the `delete` operator in `strictNullChecks`, the operand must be `any`, `unknown`, `never`, or be optional (in that it contains `undefined` in the type). Otherwise, use of the `delete` operator is an error.

[Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#operands-for-delete-must-be-optional)

Comment: Destructuring to omit the property when cloning is genius, saved me lots of TypeScript hassle, thanks!

Comment: Following from this answer, if you don't use the const `coordinate` then typescript eslint will complain that `coordinate` is "assigned a value but is never used". How would you over come this lint error?

Comment: @FezAbbas you can disable this rule for this specific case using `ignoreRestSiblings ` https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-unused-vars#ignorerestsiblings. `"@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": ["error", { "ignoreRestSiblings": true }]`

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I created a specific function taking advantage of generics, and it worked well!

```
const removeAttrFromObject = <O extends object, A extends keyof O>(
  object: O,
  attr: A
): Omit<O, A> => {
  const newObject = { ...object }

  if (attr in newObject) {
    delete newObject[attr]
  }

  return newObject
}
```

The two generics `O` and `A` are making all the magic, especially the `A` generic: `extends keyof O` says "the second parameter must be an attribute from the object".

Then inside the function, TypeScript knows for sure that `attr` is an attribute from the `object`. I double-check with the `attr in newObject` if statement, in order to make sure at runtime everything is fine too. Just pure defensive programming.

The `const newObject = { ...object }` is here to make sure we don't modify the reference passed as arg, but return a new reference instead. It's some leftovers from my functional programming old days.

Now if we try the function :

```
const test = removeAttrFromObject({ a: 1, b: 2 }, 'a')
// returns as type `Omit<{a: 1, b: 2}, 'a'>` which equals `{a: 1}`

const test2 = removeAttrFromObject({ a: 1, b: 2 }, 'c') 
// TypeScript raise an error as `'c'` is not a key from the object passed
```

Answer (score 2):

You can delete if the property is optional

```js
interface OptionalCoordinate {
   coordinate?
}

const eventData: OptionalCoordinate = {...myEvent}; // myEvent is an instance of my `Event` class
// ok to delete
delete eventData.coordinate;
```

Comment: OP is explicitly asking how to delete a non-optional property.

Answer (score 0):

What the error is telling you is that `coordinate` is not an optional property of that object (that is it can be undefined) and you are trying to delete it.

You could have deleted it if it was optional

```
coordinate?: FirebaseFirestore.Geopoint
```

It seems to have been introduced after version 4.0, you can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63702057/what-is-the-logic-behind-error-the-operand-of-a-delete-operator-must-be-opti).

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the error by casting to any:

```
const user = {
    firstName: 'billy',
    middleName: 'the',
    lastName: 'kid'
};

delete (user as any).middleName

console.log(user)
// { firstName: 'billy', lastName: 'kid' }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Loïc Goyet's solution also works when using an array of properties as input:

```
function popProperty<T extends Record<string, unknown>, K extends keyof T>(
  obj: T,
  properties: K[],
): Omit<T, K> {
  const result = { ...obj };
  for (const key of properties) {
    delete result[key];
  }
  return result;
}

const x = popProperty({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }, ['a', 'b']);
// const x: Omit<{
//   a: number;
//   b: number;
//   c: number;
// }, "a" | "b">
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35719996)

Answer (score -3):

As many people has already pointed out, the following is a workable but not recommending way as it is not type-safe:

```js
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any */
delete (eventData as any).coordinate;
```

Comment: This will shutdown any TypeScript warning, but does not makes the code safe.

TypeScript works in a way that an object typed can have additional properties from the type defined to a value, that's why the errors pop on first hand. And your solution doesn't address it